# Vaciar una cookie al hacer logout

Tags: php, html, variables, cookies

Buenos dias como puedo vaciar una cookie al hacer logout. Estuve haciendo pruebas con `unset` pero no me vacia la cookie.

**Cookie que esta en el index.php y abre un modal de bienvenida**

```
<script>
function getCookie(c_name){
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1){
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
}
if (c_start == -1){
    c_value = null;
}else{
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1){
        c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}

 function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

if(getCookie('tiendaaviso')!="1"){
$('#mensaje').modal('show');
}
 function PonerCookie(){
 setCookie('tiendaaviso','1',365);
 $('#mensaje').modal('hide');
 }
</script>
```

**Archivo logout.php**

```
<?php
 //Inicio la sesión
   session_start();

   $_SESSION["autorizado"] = "N";
   $_SESSION["user"] = "";
   $_SESSION["pass"] = "";

   $link =$_POST["link"];

   if($link == "")
   $link = "/";
   header("Location: /_admin/");

   // Destruir todas las variables de sesión.
   $_SESSION = array();

   if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]

   );
 }
 session_destroy();
 ?>
```

**Botón cerrar sesión**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
var confirmIt = function (e) {
    if (!confirm('¿Estas seguro que quieres cerrar sesión?')) 
e.preventDefault();
};
for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Lo podrias eliminar al hacer click en logout, luego redireccionas al logout. Como un paso previo. tambien lo puedes eliminar en javascript despues de mostrar el modal.

Comment: He subido a mi pregunta el javscript que tengo para el botón de cerrar sesión, haber si se puede, gracias @cardeol

Answer (score 0):

Con **JS** sería algo así:

```
const borrarCookie = (cookie) => {
 document.cookie = cookie + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

const getCookie = (cname) => {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$("#crear").on("click", () => {
  document.cookie = "tiendaaviso=tienda aviso es genial";
});

$("#eliminar").on("click", () => {
  borrarCookie("tiendaaviso");
});

$("#leer").on("click", () => {
  let valorCookie = getCookie("tiendaaviso");
  if(valorCookie != false){
    alert(`El valor de la cookie tiendaaviso es "${valorCookie}"`);
  }else{
    alert("La cookie tiendaaviso no tiene valor");
  }

});
```

Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/dmolina101/4L3e19xc/4/)

Con **PHP** sería algo así:

```
unset($_COOKIE["tiendaaviso"]);
```

Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22creando%20la%20cookie%20tiendaaviso%20%3Cbr%3E%22;%5Cnsetcookie(%22tiendaaviso%22,%22La%20Tienda%20Aviso%20es%20Genail%22);%5Cnecho%20%22el%20valor%20de%20la%20cookie%20tiendaaviso%20es:%20%22.$_COOKIE[%22tiendaaviso%22].%22%20%3Cbr%3E%22;%5Cnecho%20%22verificando%20si%20la%20cookie%20tiendaaviso%20existe%20%3Cbr%3E%22;%5Cn$resultado%20=%20verificarCokkie(%22tiendaaviso%22);%5Cnif($resultado[0])%7B%5Cn%20echo%20$resultado[1].%22,%20procediendo%20a%20eliminarla%20%3Cbr%3E%22;%5Cn%20unset($_COOKIE[%22tiendaaviso%22]);%5Cn%20echo%20%22verificando%20si%20la%20cookie%20tiendaaviso%20aun%20existe%20%3Cbr%3E%22;%5Cn%20$resultado2%20=%20verificarCokkie(%22tiendaaviso%22);%5Cn%20echo%20$resultado2[1];%5Cn%7Delse%7B%5Cn%20echo%20$resultado[1];%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnfunction%20verificarCokkie($nombre)%7B%5Cn%20if(isset($_COOKIE[$nombre]))%7B%5Cn%20return%20array(true,%22La%20cookie%20%22.$nombre.%22%20Existe%22);%5Cn%20%7Delse%7B%5Cn%20return%20array(false,%22La%20cookie%20%22.$nombre.%22%20NO%20existe%22);%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

Si aun te sigue dando error seguro la `cookie` tiene un valor multidimencional y no es de un solo nivel, para eliminarla tendrías que recorrer la `$_COOKIE` con un **loop** e ir eliminándola o si ya sabes en que nivel esta puedes eliminarla directamente, si puedes colocar un `print_r($_COOKIE)` y mostrarnos como te la muestra seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

##### Cookie caducara por reasignación de vencimiento

Lo mas sencillo es darle una fecha antigua a la cookie y utilizar el código así como lo paso:

```
<?php
setcookie("tiendaaviso", "", time()-3600);
# setcookie("nombreCookie", valores, fechaVencimiento);
?>
```

`setcookie()` lleva parámetros que si no se asignan los valores correctos puede tener resultados inesperados.

Lo que estamos haciendo con la cookie `tiendaaviso` es quitarle el valor actual `""` y darle un valor de duración del pasado `time()-3600` donde time() nos dara el tiempo en segundos presente pero se le restaran `-3600` segundos que equivalen a 1 hora, dando a entender que esa cookie no esta vigente.

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte del código:

```
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
$params["path"], $params["domain"],
$params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
```

);

Creo que en lugar de ir session_name(), debería ir con el nombre de la cookie.
Es lo que sugiere [AleBuo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/229608/alebuo) pero en tu código.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/374925)

Answer (score -1):

```
public function cerrarSesion() {
        session_destroy();
        setcookie('usuario', null, time()-1);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la cookie que quiero eliminar el navegador la guarda como "tiendaaviso", y el codigo que me pasaste me devuelve error